# Using Value of 1 for boolean in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm following [this](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/remindme/) tutorial for creating reminder in android. In the source code that it provides it used the value of "1" for a `boolean` method.

Here is the code snippet I'm talking about:

```
public static boolean showRemainingTime(){
    return "1".equals(sp.getString(TIME_OPTION, "0"));
}
```

Why "1" is used in this example given that in java the value of boolean is either true or false?

Sorry for my lame question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `showRemainingTime` method is not returning the `String` "1". It returns `true` if the `String` returned by `sp.getString(TIME_OPTION, "0")` is equal to the `String` "1", and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I was thinking wrongly about this... Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

String literals are full-fledged `String` objects.  This may make more sense to you:

```
String str = "1";
return str.equals(sp.getString(TIME_OPTION, "0"));
```

It might also make more sense if it were written this way:

```
return sp.getString(TIME_OPTION, "0").equals("1");
```

The problem with this version is that if `getString(...)` returned null, calling `equals(...)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.  That may not be possible in this particular case, but calling methods on string literals is a good habit to get into.